# aabb.IsValid() Error with Canvas Scaler and Sprites (Unity3d)

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools, aabb

I am trying to add a sprite background to my canvas.
The canvas is set to render mode Screen Space- Camera so that the canvas size matches the main camera view.
The canvas scaler is set to scale with screen size with a reference resolution of 1920 x 1080.

When I place any sprite into the canvas as a child I get errors that occurs only when unity first starts.

> aabb.IsValid()
>
> IsFinite(outDistanceForSort)
> UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI()
>
> IsFinite(outDistanceAlongView)
> UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI()

I am thinking this is a bug just with the scene/game previewer in unity itself since when I clear the error on initial load it does not come back.  I know it has to do with either the canvas scaler or the sprites since when I disable them either of them the error does not appear.  Also, I need the settings to scale as I have them set so that the background images are properly sized in different resolutions.